Write speed becomes 0
I am using tsdb-comparisons to write line protocol data to cnos DB. I find that writing always stops for a period of time and the writing speed drops to the limit. What is going on? What should be done?
The command when writing is as follows:
load_cnosdb --batch-size 100 --file ./file_name.txt --workers 10 --urls "http://ip:port"

the data, has 500 columns, type: bigint, unsign bigint, double, string,one of line as follow:
ma,ta=a_0000 line=1i,s_0="9GPUmrmUH",s_1="Ar0M",s_2="lWS",s_3="DP",s_4="6L7YRg5C",s_5="IWqBo5FN",s_6="JSfGxsVv5",s_7="jDgXRJ",s_8="6GxhQ",s_9="4ifcjfGB",s_10="VN",s_11="kBKPGwqI",s_12="wNPgWXWuO",s_13="pING6QIxZ8",s_14="ut",s_15="K9a2iZDVr",s_16="GhkPQ",s_17="55l7A",s_18="KA",s_19="t6yR5bJ",s_20="VwNW",s_21="uQdB6EWi",s_22="N2ST66hQdW",s_23="DIlXi",s_24="N69obsqS0",s_25="CxTQQfx",s_26="bRy",s_27="W5boQUwt",s_28="lUnE56ILAK",s_29="0sMIn7Ly",s_30="4pj6u72",s_31="Ogqkx",s_32="5MW4DzMayY",s_33="PX9Ggo",s_34="V0bP",s_35="5W",s_36="GN0Kxs",s_37="BWZ7J",s_38="GKwyWSl6ML",s_39="3Mv3Q",i_0=64176i,i_1=84790i,i_2=30574i,i_3=90540i,i_4=90862i,i_5=12355i,i_6=15617i,i_7=62663i,i_8=69914i,i_9=45240i,f_0=36112.7569,f_1=62979.0374,f_2=77366.3445,f_3=87750.7346,f_4=73701.0236,f_5=39141.5777,f_6=69536.3774,f_7=99770.8897,f_8=29693.8706,f_9=61607.0027,f_10=42883.7322,f_11=22544.348,f_12=25203.7178,f_13=96901.3966,f_14=7578.0402,f_15=93494.1806,f_16=64361.4859,f_17=16181.8416,f_18=22739.2287,f_19=57993.4986,f_20=57099.3535,f_21=4482.1493,f_22=29792.1013,f_23=51408.9361,f_24=80214.5874,f_25=18788.534,f_26=75924.8221,f_27=34936.0329,f_28=99139.1539,f_29=83951.0193,f_30=46813.548,f_31=75850.9813,f_32=37118.8994,f_33=30305.0699,f_34=71766.0212,f_35=70407.9017,f_36=33993.5312,f_37=25807.6732,f_38=15053.0535,f_39=62265.2021,f_40=54448.2379,f_41=34119.6448,f_42=68653.1266,f_43=52858.0914,f_44=88064.5851,f_45=37243.8941,f_46=10068.7664,f_47=62225.7413,f_48=20971.5283,f_49=81185.794,f_50=49723.4108,f_51=74931.2194,f_52=69286.601,f_53=89171.2925,f_54=34206.6647,f_55=52225.4869,f_56=64452.9768,f_57=22325.3175,f_58=16129.6275,f_59=85235.3436,f_60=37398.1135,f_61=74717.2336,f_62=59167.5237,f_63=18636.0281,f_64=90002.1387,f_65=52548.4645,f_66=39315.0478,f_67=18849.115,f_68=77778.6422,f_69=44022.5538,f_70=97107.1208,f_71=48184.4675,f_72=56405.0683,f_73=23683.2872,f_74=53177.0559,f_75=58027.7609,f_76=73003.8657,f_77=66704.8983,f_78=27931.917,f_79=94377.9308,f_80=28208.2366,f_81=93847.294,f_82=96425.0779,f_83=8902.9491,f_84=59896.9098,f_85=88573.3177,f_86=2844.5695,f_87=17239.7763,f_88=78283.5908,f_89=95863.7392,f_90=83667.7404,f_91=47954.0035,f_92=2365.3998,f_93=12188.6808,f_94=96562.968,f_95=1036.1686,f_96=18210.7932,f_97=59181.1538,f_98=35716.1537,f_99=86920.1327,f_100=97331.6575,f_101=33930.5329,f_102=62719.8232,f_103=6682.6564,f_104=41149.0241,f_105=16824.2699,f_106=85669.2511,f_107=80980.9129,f_108=6572.4562,f_109=25350.6378,f_110=4319.1883,f_111=25605.7276,f_112=41030.4115,f_113=38927.9057,f_114=53988.3247,f_115=5780.8829,f_116=25527.2487,f_117=69769.507,f_118=68655.2942,f_119=12668.2917,f_120=82533.3419,f_121=95686.5229,f_122=55815.3469,f_123=16121.9136,f_124=46827.3738,f_125=17234.6015,f_126=41275.4958,f_127=21438.618,f_128=4783.7611,f_129=59750.0169,f_130=84650.6798,f_131=37225.2194,f_132=26883.3137,f_133=88579.4544,f_134=33503.6678,f_135=49573.4615,f_136=75294.4451,f_137=94270.619,f_138=90861.5058,f_139=10752.3171,f_140=78346.8606,f_141=70226.0542,f_142=73786.1602,f_143=94345.6056,f_144=85907.6015,f_145=58674.4166,f_146=92382.5219,f_147=86951.6342,f_148=27091.5492,f_149=88641.8525,f_150=98097.128,f_151=805.3888,f_152=90228.5581,f_153=38162.6053,f_154=61574.1783,f_155=13116.0794,f_156=58018.6341,f_157=93671.5192,f_158=44837.4218,f_159=55144.4975,f_160=60627.2657,f_161=37338.4439,f_162=14632.9821,f_163=97818.9943,f_164=72860.4733,f_165=11196.2271,f_166=34274.1881,f_167=58376.6208,f_168=47802.8587,f_169=44102.4807,f_170=11401.5758,f_171=14872.9277,f_172=146.6661,f_173=60839.3782,f_174=39959.7909,f_175=75195.2257,f_176=81364.4817,f_177=2730.0242,f_178=10051.478,f_179=51234.5854,f_180=13398.7542,f_181=18919.6284,f_182=76988.4608,f_183=37327.7263,f_184=60642.3735,f_185=9212.2228,f_186=24081.4588,f_187=8358.3674,f_188=81270.5518,f_189=92493.08,f_190=19882.1508,f_191=22941.3183,f_192=54531.2897,f_193=46794.0378,f_194=22893.3079,f_195=9138.5202,f_196=96614.3879,f_197=91278.1448,f_198=39497.1141,f_199=11158.6404,f_200=27915.8611,f_201=5828.5473,f_202=77152.5781,f_203=14073.2535,f_204=71654.7419,f_205=26610.5619,f_206=50142.1678,f_207=59137.6069,f_208=98299.9433,f_209=42633.9159,f_210=61967.744,f_211=38242.7551,f_212=69953.2865,f_213=37873.2774,f_214=43634.977,f_215=92780.8092,f_216=30378.8914,f_217=4881.1513,f_218=42179.1569,f_219=15428.0196,f_220=87167.8355,f_221=76177.2097,f_222=41925.9629,f_223=41725.0005,f_224=83029.3716,f_225=74437.3048,f_226=33095.491,f_227=64736.0269,f_228=67472.9045,f_229=65318.3534,f_230=664.604,f_231=34914.4068,f_232=7197.0944,f_233=67316.4005,f_234=11755.8345,f_235=31510.5814,f_236=25546.0187,f_237=69650.5877,f_238=56413.3354,f_239=81465.1498,f_240=94159.8178,f_241=57054.4722,f_242=30912.278,f_243=66010.4137,f_244=42468.3578,f_245=84617.7745,f_246=73257.8063,f_247=82574.4735,f_248=23152.4613,f_249=13709.8505,f_250=79140.0524,f_251=31429.2484,f_252=89059.4045,f_253=28245.8046,f_254=77664.2292,f_255=69367.9878,f_256=99012.1649,f_257=49367.5159,f_258=42552.0092,f_259=94878.7513,f_260=60424.3442,f_261=57379.838,f_262=35154.372,f_263=62716.6211,f_264=55745.6879,f_265=68347.0959,f_266=71454.6427,f_267=5947.9524,f_268=62719.6456,f_269=16552.9961,f_270=88390.1425,f_271=87240.9179,f_272=76783.7037,f_273=21327.5279,f_274=39624.7117,f_275=87269.0836,f_276=25118.1899,f_277=47469.4618,f_278=55430.2771,f_279=83295.7237,f_280=89615.7094,f_281=13188.0075,f_282=64255.0088,f_283=65996.0672,f_284=6553.4853,f_285=79612.6153,f_286=56789.5657,f_287=38860.9567,f_288=98586.4965,f_289=88972.2722,f_290=57851.3507,f_291=12759.4184,f_292=52571.4412,f_293=2539.8855,f_294=69512.4534,f_295=71462.0253,f_296=26052.5308,f_297=51773.6877,f_298=3539.6442,f_299=63023.084,f_300=26360.8415,f_301=15748.248,f_302=49616.249,f_303=81137.6611,f_304=39129.2017,f_305=11810.5445,f_306=75608.0078,f_307=78716.6293,f_308=42973.7065,f_309=2823.5067,f_310=84478.1748,f_311=52157.8204,f_312=84578.1158,f_313=66644.0853,f_314=31983.877,f_315=73366.362,f_316=74230.7768,f_317=70461.128,f_318=8474.6262,f_319=21899.0532,f_320=46670.6817,f_321=19328.8766,f_322=65222.1298,f_323=10036.9288,f_324=84917.1582,f_325=71138.755,f_326=66583.3554,f_327=53360.4047,f_328=9157.8255,f_329=8192.9726,f_330=58020.2784,f_331=92697.6155,f_332=53331.4476,f_333=37850.2891,f_334=30865.0121,f_335=28532.2418,f_336=42068.3814,f_337=85817.0102,f_338=90149.2169,f_339=95778.0948,f_340=61207.223,f_341=39960.3245,f_342=55325.3515,f_343=8078.1449,f_344=13789.1401,f_345=6612.7534,f_346=21763.9953,f_347=94280.0089,f_348=12789.3922,f_349=50759.6334,f_350=46188.6667,f_351=71813.6285,f_352=54851.5218,f_353=2895.7582,f_354=10459.4136,f_355=8964.8535,f_356=29373.7108,f_357=35539.0306,f_358=57653.6731,f_359=79337.8162,f_360=36248.0191,f_361=94667.8795,f_362=20830.1314,f_363=81916.6937,f_364=85379.1936,f_365=743.1033,f_366=61707.0313,f_367=84290.9774,f_368=37696.0057,f_369=20607.0886,f_370=24949.8388,f_371=48447.5431,f_372=5145.6708,f_373=94267.0209,f_374=72991.8153,f_375=76431.2119,f_376=67901.0337,f_377=168.6039,f_378=20881.7918,f_379=14253.7939,f_380=78662.0372,f_381=76743.6114,f_382=51696.0006,f_383=85113.4707,f_384=48415.9505,f_385=90486.3977,f_386=83449.6963,f_387=93421.941,f_388=47752.8755,f_389=23922.8504,f_390=25171.3231,f_391=13744.2666,f_392=46885.9653,f_393=85603.4834,f_394=61226.3293,f_395=55787.6376,f_396=49010.1975,f_397=55848.4293,f_398=50820.0734,f_399=65276.214,f_400=47366.9214,f_401=39140.6931,f_402=26856.2951,f_403=7393.952,f_404=10721.2034,f_405=41246.1051,f_406=57437.6879,f_407=160.4073,f_408=70825.0319,f_409=44502.8735,f_410=8929.7217,f_411=17027.2336,f_412=78759.1652,f_413=17779.4889,f_414=20633.7161,f_415=67553.6691,f_416=35324.1235,f_417=87196.837,f_418=40095.3107,f_419=70767.888,f_420=52946.0776,f_421=49415.0422,f_422=64824.9153,f_423=31451.9592,f_424=60768.3383,f_425=59581.9616,f_426=48889.2054,f_427=60298.4377,f_428=20737.6027,f_429=88770.14,f_430=63106.4297,f_431=10433.1888,f_432=20140.0452,f_433=5690.0989,f_434=70026.0777,f_435=21310.8979,f_436=28049.6909,f_437=5908.4781,f_438=66731.3621,f_439=6547.2485,f_440=87911.1961,f_441=36722.309,f_442=32647.3758,f_443=17531.4794,f_444=71130.1745,f_445=30778.3658,f_446=18152.3547,f_447=20764.278,f_448=96015.5023,f_449=82223.53 1514736000000000000

create db as follow:
create database benchmark with shard 10 replica 2 vnode_duration '7d';

tsdb-comparisons log as follow:
time,per. metric/s,metric total,overall metric/s,per. row/s,row total,overall row/s
1716891001,3181247.03,3.181350E+07,3181247.03,6349.79,6.350000E+04,6349.79
1716891011,3491960.28,6.673320E+07,3336601.36,6969.98,1.332000E+05,6659.88
1716891021,2915771.89,9.589140E+07,3196324.97,5819.90,1.914000E+05,6379.89
...
1716948091,0.00,1.079645E+10,189079.68,0.00,2.154980E+07,377.40
1716948101,0.00,1.079645E+10,189046.57,0.00,2.154980E+07,377.34
1716948111,0.00,1.079645E+10,189013.47,0.00,2.154980E+07,377.27

It can be seen from the log that the real-time writing speed reached 0 in the later period.
version: cnosdb 2.3.5, revision 99e05e60eaeed98ed779326760b807b0561abf0f
db: replica 2 shard 10 vnode_duration '7d'
deploy: 3meta + 3 querytskv
Has anyone encountered similar problems?
